# How can I automatically control the transition of a Xamarin Form Carrousel that looks like a stock price presentation?

Tags: xamarin, carousel, stock

I would like to control the speed and direction of the slide's transitions in a Carousel view. I can automatially make the slides transitions  but I don't know how to control its speed nor the direction of the transition (Right to Left).

Any idea?
thanks in advance

I Start a timer to scroll each page :

```
public ItemsPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        _timer.Interval = 15000;
        _timer.Elapsed += _timer_Elapsed;
        _timer.Enabled = true;
     }
```

After the time expires I set the new page:

```
private void _timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("{0} Position.", Position);        
        Position = Position + 1;
        Position = Position % Carousel_Mycloset.Count;
        OnPropertyChanged("Position");
        

    }
```

The pages are scroll but I cannot control the speed and direction (right to left) of the transition.

Comment: Maybe you can set up a timer to control him to switch, swiping left or right by index.

Comment: I already do that. I can switch the frame left or right but the view appears .Instantaneous. It does not appear slowly and from the right. the effect that I am looking for is the same as a stock price app that shows the price of the stock in this way.

Comment: this is an example of what I would like to present in the app.https://stockx.com .

Comment: Did you try to add an animation to the layout inside the template ?

Comment: I could not find an animation example using carousel. can you kindly advice me on this. Thanks a lot for your attention

Comment: I managed to slow down the scrolling using the Scrolled property in the carousel view but I could not control it. <control:CarouselView x:Name="MyCloset"  ItemsSource="{Binding Carousel_Mycloset}" PositionChanged="OnPositionChanged"  Position="{Binding Position, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                      Scrolled="OnCarouselViewScrolled"
                                      Routing.Route=""
                                      HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"  HeightRequest="200">

Comment: Did you try to scroll the page with a delay ?

Comment: Hi Leo, I did but it does not scroll smoothly.

Comment: Is it the delay time ?Maybe you could change the time.

Comment: I edit the question with the source code. The delay does not change the speed of the transition of the pages .

Comment: Or you could try to look for some third-part library.

Comment: I looked at the sync fusion library but it is quite expensive. Do you know any other library?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is  the only library I found.